# Ionic 2 Android Production Build loads very slow

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have finished my Ionic 2 App for Android.

For testing I generated my builds with:

```
cordova build android
```

These APKs work but the device ready event takes quite a while to fire. No problem.

No I build the productions APK:

```
cordova build --release android
```

And the device ready event still happens only after a few seconds. I hoped that this would not be the case in the production version.

```
ionic run android --prod
```

This creates a build for debugging and in this build the device ready events fire very fast. But the build is called app-debug.apk.

How can I build a production build that loads fast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For production (the `--prod` uses `aot` which makes load time faster). Also make sure to use `ionic` middleware instead of `cordova`

```
ionic build --release --prod android
```

To debug in aot:

```
ionic run android --aot
```